# Exporting a war in Release mode using Spring Tool Suite STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, war, release

I´m using Spring Tool Suite for a Spring MVC project. I can´t find the option of exporting my war in release mode. Does Eclipse do this by default when exporting the war?

Maybe Eclipse use a Debug mode by default, but it changes the mode automatically when you export the war.

I know that release version is optimized, that´s why I would like to find out how to export my war in that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Debug/Release modes in eclipse when exporting jars/wars. There are Java compiler settings but they remain unchanged no matter how you export your jars.

If you want to control your build settings depending on the build profile selected, it is better to use some build engine such as Apache Maven or Gradle, where you can define multiple build profiles and then change them during the build.